# Set visibility of control based on selectedindex?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display a control based on `SelectedIndex` value, what I did so far:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
</UserControl.Resource>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="8,0,8,16" x:Name="FormTypeFilters" SelectedIndex="0">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="All" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Home" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Away" />
</ComboBox>
```

so I've a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` provided by `System.Windows.Controls`, and I've a `ComboBox` with three items.

I also have three `DataGrid`, just for example I'll post it only with declaration (without columns):

```
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=FormTypeFilters, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" />
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=FormTypeFilters, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" /> 
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=FormTypeFilters, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" />
```

I'm stuck on this point, I need to know how to tell to `BooleanConverter` that have to display the DataGrid 1 when the user select index 0, and Datagrid 2 when the user select index 1, and so on...

Comment: ***Boolean***ToVisibilityConverter. SelectedIndex is an int. Even in javascript this wouldn't work.  You need to create a custom converter and use the ConverterParameter to indicate for what index to return Visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a Binding Converter, you may use a `DataTrigger` to set the Visibility of the DataGrids.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=FormTypeFilters}"
                             Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```